# The term 'vercel' is not recognized

Tags: windows, npm, command-line-interface, npm-install, vercel

I have installed the vercel cli globally with:

```
npm i -g vercel
```

but when I run:

```
vercel login
```

or:

```
vercel --version
```

I get the following error:

> vercel : The term 'vercel' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
> function, script file, or operable program.

I don't know why the error persists. I installed vercel on powershell, cmd, adminstrator powershell and in a vsc terminal.

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

please open cmd and run as administrator and run this command-- npm install -g vercel